# How can I print off this list of viewers provided in JSON format, from a URL in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, url, twitch

The list I am attempting to print off is here: https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/joxterthemighty/chatters

My goal is to print a line containing each name under the "viewers" section of the JSON, without all the clutter that comes with it.

The following is the code I am attempting to execute:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/joxterthemighty/chatters");
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        System.out.println(json.get("viewers"));
  }
```

But that code returns the following:

```
{"chatter_count":9,"chatters":{"viewers":["anklezziix","chofl","commanderroot","electricallongboard","electricalskateboard","givemehoneynow","tbedark","vivbot"],"global_mods":[],"staff":[],"admins":[],"moderators":["joxterthemighty"]},"_links":{}}
```

Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["viewers"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:498)
    at Joxterville.JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:19)

Is "viewers" not what I would ask for it to print off? I am very confused and unfamiliar with JSON.

I am using org.json from Maven. Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: `json.get("chatters").get("viewers")`

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, is there any way I can print it without the special symbols without a mass of replaceAll?

Comment: what special symbols are you talking about?

Comment: Just get the values out of the `JSONArray` object that is returned by the call from my previous comment.

Comment: @gagansingh System.out.println(((JSONObject) json.get("chatters")).get("viewers")); 

returns this : ["anklezziix","chofl","commanderroot","electricalskateboard","givemehoneynow","tbedark","vivbot"]

I want it to just say the names, one per line

Comment: you can iterate through each element of the jsonarray and print the stringvalue of the element